# Finding beginning and end quotations

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I'm starting to write a code syntax highlighter in JavaScript, and I want to highlight text that is in quotes (both "s and 's) in a certain color. I need it be able to not be messed up by one of one type of quote being in the middle of a pair of the other quotes as well, but i'm really not sure where to even start. I'm not sure how I should go about finding the quotes and then finding the correct end quote.

Comment: Would a regex like this one help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regexp-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're doing this for the challenge, have a look at [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

For your problem, you could read up on [parsing (and lexers) at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). It's a huge topic and you'll find that you'll come upon bigger problems than parsing strings.

To start, you *could* use regular expressions (although they rarely have the accuracy of a true lexer.) A typical regular expression for matching a string is:

```
/"(?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*"/
```

And then the same for `'` instead of `"`.

Otherwise, for a character-by-character parser, you would set some kind of state that you're in a string once you hit `"`, then when you hit `"` that is not preceded by an uneven amount of backslashes (an even amount of backslashes would escape eachother), you exit the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can find quotes using regular expressions but if you're writing a syntax highlighter then the only reliable way is to step through the code, character by character, and decide what to do from there.

E.g. of a Regex

```
/("|')((?:\\\1|.)+?)\1/g
```

(matches "this" and 'this' and "thi\"s")

Answer (score 0):

use stack.. if unmatched quote found push it.. if match found pop

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a single regular expression in php using backwards references. JS does not support it and i think that's what you need if you really want to detect undefined backslashes.