# Challenge: Regex-only tokenizer for shell-assignment-like config lines

Tags: regex, tokenize

I asked the original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637688/ruby-1-9-regular-expression-to-match-unquoted-key-value-assignment/8639482#8639482), and got a practical response with mixed Ruby and Regular Expressions. Now, the purist in me wants know: **Can** this be done in regular expressions? My gut says it can. There's an ABNF floating around for bash 2.0, though it doesn't include string escapes.

**The Spec**

Given an input line that is either (1) a variable ("key") assignment from a bash-flavored script or (2) a key-value setting from a typical configuration file like `postgresql.conf`, this regex (or pair of regexen) should capture the key and value in such a way that I can use those captures to substitute a new value for that key.

You may use a different regular expression for shell-flavored and config-flavored lines; the caller will know which to use.

**There will be a 50-point bounty here.** I can't add a bounty for two days, so I won't accept an answer till then, but you can start answering immediately.  You earn points for:

- Readability (named capture groups, definitions via ?(DEFINE) or {0})
- Using a single regex instead of two
- Teaching me something about DFA
- Regex performance, if relevant
- Getting upvoted
- First to use a technique

**Example:**

Given the input

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

I should be able to write in Ruby:

```
match = THE_REGEX.match("export RAILS_ENV=production")
newline = "export #{match[:key]}=#{match[:value]}"
```

**Test cases: shell style**

```
RAILS_ENV=development     # Don't forget to change this for TechCrunch
HOSTNAME=`cat /etc/hostname`
plist=`cat "/Applications/Sublim\`e Text 2.app/Content's/Info.plist"`

# Optional bonus input: "#" present in the string
FORMAT="  ##0.00 passe\`" #comment
```

**Test cases: config style**

```
listen_addresses = 127.0.0.1 #localhost only by default
# listen_addresses = 0.0.0.0 commented out, should not match
```

For the purpose of this challenge, "regular expression" and "regex" mean the same thing and both can refer to any common flavor you like, though I prefer Ruby 1.9-compatible.

Comment: Your `plist=` seems to have a missing \`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the full specs and what exactly you want in the value capturing group, but this should work for your test cases:

```
/
^\s*+

(?:export\s++)?
(?<key>\w++)

\s*+
=
\s*+

(?<value>
  (?>  "(?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*+"
  |    '(?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*+'
  |    `(?:[^`\\]+|\\.)*+`
  |    [^#\n\r]++
  )
)

\s*+
(?:#.*+)?
$
/mx;
```

Handles comments and quotes with escapes.

Perl/PCRE flavor and quoting.

---

Example usage in Perl:

```
my $re = qr/
    ^\s*+

    (?:export\s++)?
    (?<key>\w++)

    \s*+
    =
    \s*+

    (?<value>
      (?>  "(?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*+"
      |    '(?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*+'
      |    `(?:[^`\\]+|\\.)*+`
      |    [^#\n\r]++
      )
    )

    \s*+
    (?:\#.*+)?
    $
/mx;

my $str = <<'_TESTS_';
RAILS_ENV=development     # Don't forget to change this for TechCrunch
HOSTNAME=`cat /etc/hostname`
plist=`cat "/Applications/Sublim\`e Text 2.app/Content's/Info.plist"`

# Optional bonus input: "#" present in the string
FORMAT="  ##0.00 passe\`" #comment

listen_addresses = 127.0.0.1 #localhost only by default
# listen_addresses = 0.0.0.0 commented out, should not match

TEST="foo'bar\"baz#"
TEST='foo\'bar"baz#\\'
_TESTS_


for(split /[\r\n]+/, $str){
    print "line: $_\n";
    print /$re/? "match: $1, $2\n": "no match\n";
    print "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
line: RAILS_ENV=development     # Don't forget to change this for TechCrunch
match: RAILS_ENV, development

line: HOSTNAME=`cat /etc/hostname`
match: HOSTNAME, `cat /etc/hostname`

line: plist=`cat "/Applications/Sublim\`e Text 2.app/Content's/Info.plist"`
match: plist, `cat "/Applications/Sublim\`e Text 2.app/Content's/Info.plist"`

line: # Optional bonus input: "#" present in the string
no match

line: FORMAT="  ##0.00 passe\`" #comment
match: FORMAT, "  ##0.00 passe\`"

line: listen_addresses = 127.0.0.1 #localhost only by default
match: listen_addresses, 127.0.0.1

line: # listen_addresses = 0.0.0.0 commented out, should not match
no match

line: TEST="foo'bar\"baz#"
match: TEST, "foo'bar\"baz#"

line: TEST='foo\'bar"baz#\\'
match: TEST, 'foo\'bar"baz#\\'
```

Comment: Nails it on the first try.  Thanks!