# extract substring between quotation marks ignoring \"

Tags: java, regex

My file contains some lines such as

```
"This is a string." = "This is a string's content."
" Another \" example \"" = " New example."
"My string
can have several lines." = "My string can have several lines."
```

I need to extract the substring :

```
This is a string.
This is a string's content.
 Another \" example \"
 New example.
My string
can have several lines.
My string can have several lines.
```

Here's my code:

```
String regex = "\".*?\"\\s*?=\\s*?\".*?\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file);
```

For the moment, I can get the pair of left and right part of "=". But when my substring contains " \" ", my regex dosen't do the right job.

Can anyone help me write the correct regex please ? I tried \"^[\\"] instead of \", but it didn't work..

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "\"          # Match a quote\n" +
    "(           # Capture in group number 1:\n" +
    " (?:        # Match either...\n" +
    "  \\\\.     # an escaped character\n" +
    " |          # or\n" +
    "  [^\"\\\\] # any character except quotes or backslashes\n" +
    " )*         # Repeat as needed\n" +
    ")           # End of capturing group\n" +
    "\"          # Match a quote", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that I'm on a location where i can't test this, but does

```
\".*?(?:[^\\]\")\\s*=\\s*\".*?(?:[^\\]\")
```

work?

I just replaced the
    `\"`
with
    `(?:[^\\]\")`
so they won't match if the char before them is a `\` anymore.

Comment: actually, stackoverflow kicked out some backslashes in my last line, but you can see it in the code line correctly (i hope)

Answer (score -1):

```
/"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"/
```

[Source](http://ad.hominem.org/log/2005/05/quoted_strings.php). [Also see this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes).

Comment: The source is actually Jeffrey Friedl's "Mastering Regular Expressions" (called "unrolling the loop).

Comment: (Also, he's asking for a Java Regex, this is a JavaScript regex.)