# regular expression ~ extract string

Tags: regex

I need to extract using Regular Expression from following string

```
console.log("This can be anything except double quote"),
```

followed by comma and any other string

and the extraction output is

```
console.log("This can be anything except double quote"),
```

Note that the sample string shall not be read literally (e.g. *can be anything* means a random string or symbol

```
~!@#$%^&*)
```

Any idea, what is the right regular expression for above case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Regex for quoted string with escaping quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes):

```
(console\.log\("(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"\),)
```

Comment: sample = 'console.log("Test regex =>"), abcdef';
sample.match('console\.log\("(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"\),')

Comment: thank nneonneo, i tested in ruby with above 2 lines code , it gave me error "premature end of char-class: /console\.log\("(?:[^"\]|\.)*"\),/ (RegexpError)"

Comment: You're right nneonneo, i should have changed single quote to slash in Ruby. THANKS A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this.
The simplest I could think of: `(console.log[^,]+)`

PS: This removes the comma at the end of the console statement. You can manually add that.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand the logic, are you assuming that inside double quote there is no comma?