# Using Html.Raw() within an iframe

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, razor

I am implementing a linqpad util to get the html formatted results from a serialized object, however, it is including it's own CSS in the process when I dump the raw HTML in my view. I want to encapsulate this within an iframe to preserve all of the other CSS.

The issue I am running into is the quotation marks within the string `DumpHTML`

For context Writes to my model

```
var writer = LINQPad.Util.CreateXhtmlWriter(true);
writer.Write(objectToSerialize);
strHTML = writer.ToString();
```

Just dumping the results onto the page

```
$(function () {
        var ifrm = document.getElementById('myIframe');
        ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
        ifrm.document.open();
        ifrm.document.write('@Html.Raw(Model.DumpHTML)');
        ifrm.document.close();
    });
```

This is what is happening with my output:

```
$(function () {
        var ifrm = document.getElementById('myIframe');
        ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
        ifrm.document.open();
        ifrm.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="Generator" content="LINQ to XML, baby!" />
  <style type='text/css'>
body
{
    margin: 0.3em 0.3em 0.4em 0.5em;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 80%;
    ....
```

Is there any way around this?  Ultimately the issue is all of the auto generated styles are overriding the css on the page.

Comment: Have you tried removing the style tag from the string

Comment: I need the style tag to format the auto generated table sadly.  So i'm in the position of having to maintain the styling while not inhibiting the styling of the rest of my page.

Comment: I am assuming, the styling for table is constant? You can extract that and remove style tag.

Comment: I cannot guarantee that the styling is always constant as I have only just started working with this.  I suppose that could be an option and I'll have to preserve the styling elsewhere.  Being able to just push this to the iframe was the quick solution. If it turns out that I cannot do it then I will go the other route.

Comment: I just ended up navigating to a new page.

Comment: You said you were having problems with quotes, did you try escaping the quotes before passing it in `HTML.Raw()`

Comment: That would have required me to loop through the string and escape all the quotes programmatically. I didn't want to do all that.

Comment: You could use regex. It's significantly faster.

Comment: Here I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes)

Comment: This is true, However I already solved my problem through another means, going to close this question.