# Parse a string from a string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex that will parse a string from a string.

To show you what I mean, imagine that the following is the **content** of the string to parse:

```
"a string" ... \\"another \"string\"\\" ... "yet another \"string" ... "failed string\"
```

where "..." denotes some arbitrary data.

The regex would need to return the list:

```
["a string", "another \"string\"\\", "yet another \"string"]
```

**Edit: Note that the literal backslashes don't stop the second match**

I've tried finditer but it won't find overlapping matches, and I tried the lookahead (?=) but I couldn't get that to work either.

Help?

Comment: What have you attempted so far, please provide that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for quoted string with escaping quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex to match the strings that starts with `"` (*which was not preceded by `\` symbol*) upto the next `"` symbol which also not preceded by `\`

```
(?<!\\)".*?(?<!\\)"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sX9fR0/3)

```
>>> s = r'"a string" ... "another \"string\"" ... "yet another \"string" ... "failed string\"'
>>> m = re.findall(r'".*?[^\\]"', s)
>>> m
['"a string"', '"another \\"string\\""', '"yet another \\"string"']
>>> m = re.findall(r'".*?(?<!\\)"', s)
>>> m
['"a string"', '"another \\"string\\""', '"yet another \\"string"']
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?<!\\)".*?(?<!\\)"', s)
>>> m
['"a string"', '"another \\"string\\""', '"yet another \\"string"']
```

**UPDATE:**

```
>>> s = r'"a string" ... \\"another \"string\"\\" ... "yet another \"string" ... "failed string\" '
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?<!\\)".*?(?<!\\)"|(?<=\\\\)".*?\\\\"', s)
>>> m
['"a string"', '"another \\"string\\"\\\\"', '"yet another \\"string"']
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
"a string"
"another \"string\"\\"
"yet another \"string"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sX9fR0/6)

Comment: That works to an extent but I added a second case that I had forgot about before, that being the literal backslash character before quotes. Please refer the the OP and if you could help out that would be great.

Comment: @globby updated... it's the python behaviour of escaping the backslash one more time.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out myself. Thanks. Used `(?<!(?<!\\)\\)".*?(?<!(?<!\\)\\)"`

Comment: I don't believe that is relevant, due to the fact that I didn't need it to match that case ;p

Comment: do you have any further problem?both regexes matches the same set of words i think..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60324/discussion-between-avinash-raj-and-globby).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
"[\w\s\\"]+(?<!\\)"
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/sX9fR0/4)**

[image]

**Edit**: I noticed you updated your input sample. For the updated input, you can use this regex:

```
(?:\\\\"|")[\w\s\\"]+(?:\\\\"|(?<!\\)")
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/sX9fR0/5)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A way that emulate an atomic group *(that is interesting to reduce the backtracking when the pattern must fail)*:

```
re.findall(r'"(?=((?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*))\1"', s)
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/xZ8dM6/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
("[^...]*?")(?=\s*\.\.\.|$)
```

You can try this.

See demo.Works correctly to give the required answer.

http://regex101.com/r/bJ6rZ5/4