# Regex to extract query parameters fails with DateTime Strings

Tags: java, regex

Suppose the folowing SQL command:

```
update [TABLE] set [value] = 'UserName' where key1 = :param1 and key2 = :param2
```

I would like to extract `:param1` and `:param2` from the SQL. So, I´m using the following regex to match the SQL String:

```
:([\w.$]+|"[^"]+"|'[^']+')
```

This is working fine, **except** when the SQL String contains a colon (:) between quotes (") or single quotes (').

Eg, I would like that the regex matcher returns me only `:param1` and `:param2` to the following queries as well:

```
 update [TABLE] set [value] = ':UserName' where key1 = :param1 and key2 = :param2
 update [TABLE] set [value] = 'User=:UserName' where key1 = :param1 and key2 = :param2
 update [TABLE] set [value] = '2015-04-26 21:59:24' where key1 = :param1 and key2 = :param2
```

because the values *:UserName*, *User=:UserName* and *2015-04-26 21:59:24* are between Single Quotes...

I tried to modify the regex expression, but nothing seems to work. What should I do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes for examples of how to use a regex to match (and therefore also to exclude from matching) quoted text with escape sequences.

Comment: @BadZen, I tried some aproaches with my expression, but none of them worked... I´m not proficient on regex so, I know that I´m making some mistake, but I don´t know where... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/'.*?'|(:[^\b]+?\b)/g
```

Your results will be in group #1 (the paren match).

[Demo of this regex](http://regexr.com/3atep).

EDIT: As per weirdness discussed below:
         /'.*?'|(:\B+?\b)/g

Comment: That said, why are you parsing raw SQL yourself?   Normally that's a "code smell" and there's a better way to go...

Comment: Hello @BadZen, thanks for your comment. 
I tried to use your expression on Java (using Java Pattern.compile) but it´s trowing as exception: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 11
'.*?'|(:[^\b]+?\b). Is there another approach that I could use?

You also asked me why Am I parsing the query by my own. It´s due to some restrictions on the Android platform that doesn´t allows me to use "named parameters" and another issues. So, the only viable solution that fits our project e to create a "layer" that will handle named parameters just as we need.

Comment: That's gonna be tough specially with the example of `'User=:UserName' ` in the second query. I'll suggest using a differnt syntax for named parameter that is less common than a semi-colon. let's say something like `[:namedparameter:]` for example.

Comment: I guess I can't convince you to use indexed parameters then huh?   =)   This stuff is def. gonna break at some point.  Meh.

Comment: \b *is* supported in Java.  Are you sure you're escaping the string correctly?   Should look like `String REGEX_STR = "/'.*?'|(:[^\\b]+?\\b)/g";`

Comment: Otherwise you'll have literal \b in your regex.  No bueno.

Comment: @GarisMSuero - Named parameter syntax is not something OP invented, it's standard JDBC.   He can't "change it".  And look at my demo link, the regex I gave handles the situation.

Comment: WEIRD.  Java is actually picky about \b in character classes.   I think it's a bug.   Use \B instead of [^\b].   Edited above.   weird,weird.

Comment: Yes, It´s really weird! By the way, using `"/'.*?'|(:[^\B]+?\b)/g` (The escaped java string is `"'.*?'|(:[^\\B]+?\b)"` worked as a charm!!

Comment: did i misread then? I thought he said he is writing a layer in order to support named parameters. @BadZen

Comment: JDBC has them, but various JDBC drivers say "nope".   It's a sad state of affairs.  Esp. since some JPA drivers say "nope" to /positional parameters/ and want you to use named.   Headaches ensue.