# Escape string as single quoted string

Tags: javascript

I have a string which I want to encode as a single quoted Javascript string.
In other words, I want a function `asSingleQuotedString`, such that:

```
> console.log(asSingleQuotedString("Hello \"friend\" it's me."))
'Hello "friend" it\'s me'
```

I have tried using `JSON.stringify()`, which works, but gives *double* quoted strings instead.

Comment: If anyone wonders *why* I want to do something like this: It is for extracting data from the memory so it can be hard coded in a Javascript file. I want single quoted strings because the strings contains a lot of double quotes (and hardly any single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution. It works by converting to JSON format, unescaping the doublequotes, escaping single quotes and then replacing the outer double quotes with single quotes.

```
// Changes a double quoted string to a single quoted one
function doubleToSingleQuote(x) {
    return x.replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\'/g, "\\'").replace(/^"|"$/g, "'");
}

// Encodes a string as a single quoted string
function asSingleQuotedString(x) {
    return doubleToSingleQuote(JSON.stringify(x));
}
```

This method also works for arbitrary data structures, by utilizing [this regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/249937/939108) for finding all quoted strings:

```
// Encodes as JSON and converts double quoted strings to single quoted strings
function withSingleQuotedStrings(x) {
    return JSON.stringify(x).replace(/"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"/g, doubleToSingleQuote);
}
```