# Javascript Regex to match value of JSON key value pair

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following key value pairs, how could I match just the values (including the quotes)?

**Explanation**: I'm doing a find and replace in my IDE. I have hundreds of key/value pairs where the values need to be changed from strings to objects. So basically replacing the value.

```
"ElevationFilenameIn": "Input raster elevation file",
"TargetCRS": "Target vertical coordinate reference system Type",
"featureName": "The name of the feature to extract, for example \"Vegetation\" or \"Water\"",
"TargetCRScode": "Target vertical coordinate system Code",
"TargetCRSfile": "The projection (.prj) file in shoebox to be used for this inputfile"
```

[My attempt](https://regex101.com/r/sX8qU8/2) (which is not working, not even close):

```
[:]\s*(\"\w*\")
```

Comment: Add compete code **[mcve]**

Comment: You can use [`JSON.parse(string)[key_name]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: You can use ("(.*?)") but I doubt if that is what you really need/want

Comment: No need to bracket the colon, or even include it in the regex. This should do it...  `(\".*\"),`   Do not forget to add that trailing comma in your replacement.

Comment: @user6188402 Yes, that could be a possibility as well. I've updated my question to include escaped quotes.

Comment: With or without escaped quotes, you can parse the string to get the object and then access the key's value

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors That will match the keys, not just the values. That's why he has the colon.

Comment: @user6188402 How do you parse a string in an IDE's find/replace dialogue?

Comment: @Barmar. I copy the text to my browser console ;)

Comment: @user6188402 that's a good idea.

Comment: @Barmar That is why I instead added a **comma**. ;)

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors So now it will match from the beginning of the key to the end of the value.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes for how to match a quoted string including escaped quotes inside it.

Comment: @Barmar: so add a lazy directive then. I cannot do that at the moment as I am now on a mobile device and in a hurry. :)

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Laziness won't solve the problem. That will cause the regexp to stop as soon as a match is found, but doesn't make it start later than necessary. That's why he needs to skip over the `:` before starting.

Comment: @Barmar A match will not be found on the key because there is a **comma** at the end of the regex. So the regex will match the value and the comma, with the first replacement group being the value (quotes included).

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors There's no comma after the last value, so it won't match that one.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors When you get to a real browser, I suggest you try your idea at regex101.com.

Comment: @Barmar That last value he can replace manually. And **you** can be a smidgeon helpful, see the spirit of what I am trying to do and post a viable solution in stead of laying effort on going "that won't work" over and over. :-/

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Someone already posted an answer, and I posted a link to a related question. Why didn't you post your solution as an answer if you think it's right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the pattern:

```
[:]\s(\".*\")
```

and test it following this link: https://regex101.com/r/nE5eV3/1

Comment: what if it was a object e.g. `"ElevationFilenameIn": { "foo": "bar" }`

Comment: @EdwinIkechukwu, do you need to match the entire string `{ "foo": "bar" }` including braces?

Comment: How to get a single value based on the key?

Comment: This fails if multiple key value pairs present in same line eg. https://regex101.com/r/AgpwcS/1

Answer (score 8):

I guess this one does the job also well. One good part it doesn't use any capture groups one bad part it's more costly compared to the accepted answer.

```
[^:]+(?=,|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qHuhHsE6w1fLqOvP)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nE5eV3/3)

Comment: and `[^:\"]+(?=,|$)` to get rid of the quotes :)

Answer (score 2):

### Get value

`[^:"]+(?="})`

[image]

### Get value by key

If you wish to select a specific key that can be done like so:

`[^:KEY"]+(?="})`

[image]

Comment: Is this working?

Answer (score 2):

All key value par in complex JSON object.

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*"(?=:):[a-zA-Z0-9 "-ć]*(?<=")|"[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*"(?=:):[a-zA-Z0-9 "-ć]*(?=,)|"[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*"(?=:):[a-zA-Z0-9 "-ć]*(?=\w+)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a value by itself without capturing the key:

```
(?:\"keyname)(?:\"\s?:\s?\")(.*)(?:\")
```

For example given:

```
{"keyname":"value"}
```

This will capture

```
value
```

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/Bm1mmK/1

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that works when the value is another json object:

```
:\s*["{](.*)["}]\s*[,}]
```

It does not include the quotes/brackets in the capture group. If you want to include those, the capture group is easily modified:

```
:\s*(["{].*["}])\s*[,}]
```

The expressions also handle varying whitespace since json ignores whitespace.