# regex to match a single quote string that could contain ''' '' '''

Tags: python, regex

Input string could be :

```
- "his 'pet''s name is tom' and she is 2 years old"
- " '''' "
- " '' "
- "function('name', test, 'age')"
```

I want to get the single quote string from these inputs which may even contain `''` inside the single quote string.

I tried negative lookahead `(?!')` to ignore the `''` while matching.

```
 '.*?'(?!')
```

I expect output of

```
- 'pet''s name is tom'
- ''''
- 'name' and 'age'
```

Comment: do we want `pet` and `s name is tom` or `pet''s name is tom`

Comment: `pets''s name is tom`

Comment: Is it because it is empty between those quotes? Because otherwise `- "function('name', test, 'age')"` this would be `name', test, 'age`

Comment: Not empty. It is something like a escape character  `  ''  `  means  `  '  `  inside a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex match text in either single or double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967465/regex-match-text-in-either-single-or-double-quote)

Comment: @prashantrana Thanks for the answer. But that doesnt solve this problem . The problem here is ,  there can be a two consecutive single quote within a single quote string

Comment: Try `r"(?<!')'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'"`

Comment: Or just `r"'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'"`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mwmbvE/1)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider also upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may achieve that with

```
r"'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mwmbvE/1)

**Explanation**

- `'` - a single quotation mark
- `[^']*` - 0+ chars other than single quotation mark
- `(?:''[^']*)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `''` -  two single quotation marks
  - `[^']*` - 0+ chars other than single quotation mark
- `'` - a single quotation mark

[Regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re='%5B%5E'%5D*(%3F%3A''%5B%5E'%5D*)*'):

[image]

Comment: @ArunKumar Glad it worked for you. Please also consider [upvoting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) if it turned out useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

`r"'(.+?)'"` To get the single quote string

```
import re 

tx = "his 'pet''s name is tom' and she is 2 years old"

print(re.findall(r"\'(.+?)\'",tx)) 
#output :  ['pet', 's name is tom']
```

Comment: I think that to fullfill the request you should replace the "+" with a "*" inside of your regex, currently you are getting two matches, while you should get only one

Comment: same thing , to get only one, delete this `?` out this `["pet''s name is tom"]`