# JavaScript single quote using regex specific matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I am learning regex and I want to do regex matching. However, I can't escape single quote properly using code the below. So, I am getting " [ 'Hell\'o', 'World' ] ". Probably I can use /[^\s]+/g for the quick answer  " [ 'Hell'o', 'World' ] " other than the code below. However, it's hard for me to understand how regex system works if I use it. Is it possible to use other regex matching tokens for escape single quote when it outputs?

```js
function printWords(str) {
  var count = 0;
  var arr = str.match(/[\w’]+/g);
  console.log(arr);
  
}
printWords("Hell'o　World ")
```

--

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you want, but I'm getting this result, which looks fine to me: ["Hell'o", "World"]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for quoted string with escaping quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes)

Comment: `Is it possible to use other regex matching tokens for escape single quote when it outputs` - The code you posted works as you described it. What is the issue? Do you have an input with an expected output that is not achieved?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, this is much easier with `.replace`

Comment: @Fran I want to get “Hell’o” not using “/[^\s]+/g “. I want to add something into regex “/[\w’]+/g” for the answer. Thank you everyone. I will see the link which seems provide what I want to know!

Comment: Ah, I see, you just want an alternative to your working code. In that case it might be better off on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Fran Thanks, I’ll try it there. I’m still new here. It’s also good to know this might not be on-topic here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure if I understood you correctly if not please don't give mi minus :) But if I use your code and change single quote to normal single quote it works the same way as `/[^\s]+/g`. So I guess it's what you wanted. If not, then sorry :)

```js
function printWords(str) {
  var count = 0;
  var arr = str.match(/[\w']+/g);
  console.log("/[\w']+/g\n", arr);
}
printWords("Hell'o　World ");

function printWordss(str) {
  var count = 0;
  var arr = str.match(/[^\s]+/g);
  console.log("/[^\s]+/g\n", arr);
}
printWordss("Hell'o　World ")
```

Regards, KJ

Comment: I am still getting my same output as before on repl.it online editor, It should work as you are doing here. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: So I guess the problem is in repl.it. It propably changes normal single quote to it's own and don't recognize it.

Comment: If you're still interested I checked it on repl.it. And it works properly. ([repl](https://repl.it/repls/GeneralAthleticAmericancrayfish)) It displays `[ 'Hell\'o', 'World' ]` because the answer is printed in single quotes so backslash is an infrmation that single quote that's next to it is not a closing quote to the string "hell'o". I hope You understand what I mean :)

Comment: Okay. So, Repl.it decided it to express like that.  It’s confusing though.Here and there are different! Thanks.