# Search numbers between quotation marks and remove it (VS Code)

Tags: regex, string, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I've a really big `.json` file with this structure:

```
[
  "9": {
    "id": 9,
    "chapter": 4
  },
  "4": {
    "id": 82,
    "chapter": 32
  },
]
```

I want to remove every quotation marks before the brackets. The file should looking like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 9,
    "chapter": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 82,
    "chapter": 32
  },
]
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877459/how-to-find-and-replace-a-particular-character-but-only-if-it-is-in-quotes/48953880), but the result isn't that what I want.

Comment: object of object without keys are not valid objects

Comment: sorry, mistake from me. Check the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this step will remove keys; what are looking for( assuming no nested objects )  :
>
> > `"\d+":\s*{` replace with `'{'`
>
> <s>this will remove latest `,`if exist and turn last `}` to `]`</s>
>
> > `},?\s*}$` replace with `'}]'`
>
> **optional step**: this will remove latest `,`if exist
>
> > `},?\s*]$` replace with `'}]'`

---

check code snippet below for working example from your input to a valid json:

copy the pattern between `//` and paste it to vs-code find bar; (e.g. `/},?\s*]$/` will be `},?\s*]$`) to be used in VSCode and the likewise for the replace

```js
const input = `[
  "9": {
    "id": 9,
    "chapter": 4
  },
  "4": {
    "id": 82,
    "chapter": 32
  },
]`

const step1Find = /"\d+":\s*{/g;const step1Replace = '{'

//not needed anymore
//const step2Find = /^{/;const step2Replace = '['

//removing lastest comma if exists
const step3Find = /},?\s*]$/;const step3Replace = '}]'

let stringObject = input
.replace(step1Find,step1Replace)
.replace(step3Find,step3Replace)


console.log(JSON.parse(stringObject))
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Please check the updated question again, I did a mistake.