# Regex to remove all instance of letter outside of quotes

Tags: regex

I have a string of text:

```
\n new"test \n aaaa" \n ta \n `this is a \n newline that should be kept`
```

My goal is to match all `\n`'s outside of backticks (`), quotes ("), or single quotes ('). Based off another question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48953880/14465957), I switched the positive lookahead used to a negative one, which now matches all newlines outside of quotes ("). However, it doesn't work when I attempted to ignore single and back ticks.

What am I doing wrong?

Working quotes:
https://regex101.com/r/ooqz5d/1/

Comment: I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67830043/11329890) for use in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PCRE, you can use a control verb to skip everything inside of a quote closure:

```
(['"`]).*?\1(*SKIP)(*F)|\\n
```

```
(['"`])         any type of quote, put it in group 1
.*?             any characters, non greedy
\1              the quote that captured in group 1
(*SKIP)(*F)     skip the current match, which is a quote closure
|\\n            match a \n
```

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/TfOSjD/1/)

---

Also, if you need to ignore escaped quotes(`\"`, `\'` etc), you may try

```
(['"`])(?:(?<!\\)\\(?:\\\\)*\1|(?!\1).)*\1(*SKIP)(*F)|\\n
```

Check the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/fGqrbu/1/)

---

#### Using JavaScript

For JavaScript, you can't use control verbs. But you can use group capture to replace outbound `\n`

- Regex

```
((['"`])[\s\S]*?\2)|\\n
```

- Substitution

```
$1
```

```js
const regex = /((['"`])[\s\S]*?\2)|\\n/g;

const text = String.raw`\nnew"test\naaaa"\nta\n\`this is a \nnewline that should be kept\`\ntest\n'this \n should also be kept'\n`;

console.log('before\n', text);

const result = text.replace(regex, '$1');

console.log('after\n', result);
```

- Real line breaks

```js
const regex = /((['"`])[\s\S]*?\2)|\n/g;

const text = `\nnew"test\naaaa"\nta\n\`this is a \nnewline that should be kept\`\ntest\n'this \n should also be kept'\n`;

console.log('before\n----\n', text);

const result = text.replace(regex, '$1');

console.log('after\n----\n', result);
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because of the simplicity, an the added fact that you went the extra step with the escape quotes. Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: Just went to test this is my JS program and realized that it doesn't work (in JS). Is there a reason for this? Thanks! (regex101: https://regex101.com/r/Vv1fPi/1)

Comment: @divinelemon JavaScript regex engine doesn't support control verbs! You need to specify which regex flavour you are using when you ask a question about regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
text.replace(/("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|`[^`\\]*(?:\\.[^`\\]*)*`)|\\n/g, '$1')
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/axpI2U/2/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"\\]*                  any character except: '"', '\\' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"\\]*                  any character except: '"', '\\' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^'\\]*                  any character except: ''', '\\' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'\\]*                  any character except: ''', '\\' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    `                        '`'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^`\\]*                  any character except: '`', '\\' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^`\\]*                  any character except: '`', '\\' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    `                        '`'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n                        'n'
```

**JavaScript code**:

```js
const text = String.raw`\nnew"test\naaaa\\\n"\nta\n\`this is a \nnewline that should be kept\`\n'this is a \nnew test'\n`
console.log(text.replace(/("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|`[^`\\]*(?:\\.[^`\\]*)*`)|\\n/g, '$1'))
```