# How to extract groups contains desired string from between quotes using regex?

Tags: python, regex, quotes

I would like to extract some strings from between quotes using regular expression. The text is shown below:

```
CCKeyUpDomReady('test.asmx/asdasd', 'QMlPJZTOH09XOPCcbB2jcg==', '0OO6h+G2Tzhr5XWj1Upg0A==', '0OO6h+G2Tzhr5XWj1Upg0A==', '/qqwweq2.asmx/qqq')
```

Expected result must be:

```
test.asmx/asdasd
/qqwweq2.asmx/qqq
```

How can I do it? Here is the platform for testing:
https://regexr.com/3n142

**The criteria:** string which is between quotes must contains "asmx" word. The text is much more than showed above. You can think like that you are searching asmx urls in a website source code.

Comment: Stuff all that into an array, take the first and last item in the array.  You should clarify in the question, what is the criteria for the match if it's based upon something besides position though.

Comment: What are the rules the first and last element share? Is it just that they're first/last?

Comment: Try [`'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*asmx(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'`](https://regex101.com/r/jvjmSH/1)

Comment: For me personally with the updated criteria I would put all of it in a array, then just loop (or map) and simply look for /asmx/   There are more clever regex solutions but this one will be easy to read and maintain.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @CeylanB. which language are you using?

Comment: @ctwheels it doesn't matter. Let's say python.

Comment: @ctwheels thanks for your quick reply. It worked.

Comment: @ctwheels can you give an explanation about your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/jvjmSH/2/)

```
'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)*asmx(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*)'
```

- `'` Match this literally
- `((?:[^'\\]|\\.)*asmx(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*` This is a beautiful trick gathered from [PhiLho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/249937/3600709) to [Regex for quoted string with escaping quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes). It matches escaped `'` or any other character.
  - `asmx` The OP's search string/criterion
  - `(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*` This again
- `'` Match this literally

The result is in capture group:

```
test.asmx/asdasd
/qqwweq2.asmx/qqq
```