# Regex Quiz. Quoted text with escapes

Tags: regex, pcre

Quiz:

> Validate a line in quotes. Return one (and only one) backreference
>   with the text. ie: quoted text from "quoted text". Note: a \ escapes
>   any char, so \" is a valid escape.

I know it's a common question and already been answered lots of times, but the problem is that no answer fits the correct for this quiz.

I started from simple (empty quotes are valid, should return null value in the backreference):

```
(?<=\s|^)"(.*?[^\\])?"(?=\s|$)
```

> It shouldn't match "text"with quote". Only escaped quotes are allowed
>   inside the main (opening and closing) quotes. You could use [^"].

Tried with backreferencing

```
((?<![\\])['"])((?:.(?!(?<![\\])\1))*.?)\1
```

> You're using more than 1 group. Please only allow your pattern to set
>   one backreference.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes, try `(["\']).*?(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\1`, or `"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"`

Comment: Last one works, thanks

Comment: So, it is https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786066/3832970 with the nested group turned into non-capturing.

Answer (score 0):

This one was accepted by quiz

```
^"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"$
```