# Get second string parameter of function call from c sources with regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to parse the SQLite sources for error messages and my current approach has most cases covered, I think.

My regex:

```
(?:sqlite3ErrorMsg|sqlite3MPrintf|sqlite3VdbeError)\([^;\"]+\"([^)]+)\"(?:,|\)|:)
```

Source snippet (not valid C, only for demonstration):

```
    sqlite3ErrorMsg(pParse, variable);       
    sqlite3ErrorMsg(pParse, "row value misused");
    ){
      sqlite3ErrorMsg(pParse, "no \"such\" function: %.*s", nId, zId);
      pNC->nErr++;
    }else if( wrong_num_args ){
      sqlite3ErrorMsg(pParse,"wrong number of arguments to function %.*s()",
           nId, zId);
      pNC->nErr++;
    }
        if( pExpr->iTable<0 ){
          sqlite3ErrorMsg(pParse,
            "second argument to likelihood must be a "
            "constant between 0.0 and 1.0");
          pNC->nErr++;
        }
    }else if( wrong_num_args ){
      sqlite3ErrorMsg(pParse,"factory must return a cursor, not \\w+", 
           nId);
      pNC->nErr++;
```

This successfully outputs the following capture groups:

```
row value misused
no \"such\" function: %.*s
second argument to likelihood must be a "
                "constant between 0.0 and 1.0
factory must return a cursor, not \\w+
```

However, it misses `wrong number of arguments to function %.*s()` - because of the `()`.

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/GUenKU/1)

I have also tried to capture from `"` to `"` with a negative look-behind to allow escaped `\"` (as not to skip over `no \"such\" function: %.*s`), but I could not get it to work, because my regex-foo is not that strong and there's also the cases of the multiline strings.

I've also tried to combine the answers from [Regex for quoted string with escaping quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/) with my regex, but that did not work for me, either.

The genereal idea is:

There's a function call with one of the three mentioned function names (sqlite3ErrorMsg|sqlite3MPrintf|sqlite3VdbeError), followed by a non-string parameter that I'm not interested in, followed by at least one parameter that may be either a variable (don't want that) or a string (that's what I'm looking for!), followed by an optional arbitrary number of parameters.

The string that I want may be a multiline-string and may also contain escaped quotes, parenthesis and whatever else is allowed in a C string.

I'm using Python 3.7

Comment: Try `(?:sqlite3ErrorMsg|sqlite3MPrintf|sqlite3VdbeError)\s*\(\s*\w+,((?:\s*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")+)`, see https://regex101.com/r/8hErbH/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow, that was fast an works almost perfectly. Could you move the quotes out of the capture group and post it as an answer?

Comment: Quotes will have to be removed "manually", otherwise, you won't be able to match multiline strings, like you have in `"second argument to likelihood must be a "
            "constant between 0.0 and 1.0"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok, no problem, ``strip('" ')`` should get rid of them. (Edit: strip not working as I want, still no problem, I can handle it from there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider the following pattern:

```py
(?:sqlite3ErrorMsg|sqlite3MPrintf|sqlite3VdbeError)\s*\(\s*\w+,((?:\s*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8hErbH/1). You will need to remove the delimiting double quotes manually from each line in a match.

**Details**:

- `(?:sqlite3ErrorMsg|sqlite3MPrintf|sqlite3VdbeError)` - one of the three substrings
- `\s*\(\s*` - a `(` char enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `,` - a comma
- `((?:\s*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")+)` - Group 1: one or more repetitions of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
  - `"` - a `"`
  - `[^"\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `\` and `"`
  - `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - zero or more repetitions of a `\` and then any char followed with zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`
  - `"` - a `"` char.

Sample [Python code](https://ideone.com/kbDU5g):

```py
import re
file = "sqlite3ErrorMsg(pParse, variable);       \n    sqlite3ErrorMsg(pParse, \"row value misused\");\n    ){\n      sqlite3ErrorMsg(pParse, \"no \\\"such\\\" function: %.*s\", nId, zId);\n      pNC->nErr++;\n    }else if( wrong_num_args ){\n      sqlite3ErrorMsg(pParse,\"wrong number of arguments to function %.*s()\",\n           nId, zId);\n      pNC->nErr++;\n    }\n        if( pExpr->iTable<0 ){\n          sqlite3ErrorMsg(pParse,\n            \"second argument to likelihood must be a \"\n            \"constant between 0.0 and 1.0\");\n          pNC->nErr++;\n        }\n    }else if( wrong_num_args ){\n      sqlite3ErrorMsg(pParse,\"factory must return a cursor, not \\\\w+\", \n           nId);\n      pNC->nErr++;"
rx = r'(?:sqlite3ErrorMsg|sqlite3MPrintf|sqlite3VdbeError)\s*\(\s*\w+,((?:\s*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")+)'
matches = [" ".join(map(lambda x: x.strip(' "'), m.strip().splitlines())) for m in re.findall(rx, file)]
print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['row value misused', 'no \\"such\\" function: %.*s', 'wrong number of arguments to function %.*s()', 'second argument to likelihood must be a constant between 0.0 and 1.0', 'factory must return a cursor, not \\\\w+']
```

Comment: I've changed the regex slightly and replaced ``\w+`` with ``[^,]+``, because sometimes the first parameter could be ``&sParse`` or ``Parse->someValue``. And instead of ``strip(' "')`` I've used ``strip()[1:-1]``, because the string itself could end with an escaped quote. Thanks again!