# Extract words in quotes from a string

Tags: regex, vba, string, quotes

I need to extract the substring in escaping quotes from the string.

For example, in the string

> I open my eyes and said "hello to the "world"

I need

> "hello to the "world"

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes) contains regex patterns to resolve the issue, but not for VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easy way of writing that as a Regular expression would be:

```
""".+"""
```

Reference to how to use Regex in VBA:
[How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Tested using this example code

```
Sub RegexMatchingAndDisplayingAPattern()
Dim stringOne As String
Dim regexOne As Object
Dim theMatches As Object
Dim Match As Object
Set regexOne = New RegExp

regexOne.Pattern = """.+"""
stringOne = "(I open _my eyes_ and said  ""hello to the ""world"")"

Set theMatches = regexOne.Execute(stringOne)

For Each Match In theMatches
  Debug.Print Match.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tested the pattern and it works!

Comment: Also thanks for the link how to use Regex, I'll examine it for the future.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex to do this, try:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim s As String
    s = "(I open my eyes and said ""hello to the ""world"")"
    Debug.Print s
    s = Mid(Left(s, InStrRev(s, """")), InStr(s, """"))
    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

This prints

```
(I open my eyes and said "hello to the "world")
"hello to the "world"
```