# PCRE2 regular expressions match string quote asymmetry in PHP function arguments

Tags: regex

PREG:

`(?<CV>\$*\w+\s*)\s*\((\s*(?<PRM>(\g<0>)|(?<STRING>(?<Q>['"])[^(?P=Q)]*(?P=Q))|(\g<CV>))\s*([\,]\s*(\g<PRM>))*)?\s*\)`

Here's a regex I wrote based on PCRE2. It matches most PHP functions, including more complex nested functions such as:

```php
bar("",bar($str,CONST,func($s,o)))
```

But I ran into a problem: I couldn't solve the problem with mismatched double quotes like this:

```php
bar("string"",bar($str,CONST,func($s,o))) //1
bar("string\",bar($str,CONST,func($s,o))) //2
bar("",bar($str,CONST,func($s,o))) //This regex is supported, but when I try to be compatible with both cases, the problem occurs
```

Comment: Any chance you could use a proper parser instead? https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser

Comment: Yes, I need it, thanks. But this question makes me sick

Comment: `[^(?P=Q)]*` is probably not doing what you might think it does. It matches [characters besides](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `)(?=QP`. You could use a [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) e.g. `(?:(?!(?P=Q)).)*` but it's more efficient if you used an [unrolled](https://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) pattern, e.g. [`"(?:[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'(?:[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'`](https://regex101.com/r/jhT8v7/1) also considering escaped quotes.

Comment: You really solved my confusion, I learned new knowledge,stackoverflow is more wonderful because of you

Comment: @cgxg Glad that helped, yes I learn a lot here on Stackoverflow all the time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@bobble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble),Problem has been solved, I can alternate single quotes and double quotes `|` statement as two ways to write, so you can avoid a lot of unnecessary problems.

---

Edit from @bobblebubble:

It looked like you expected the [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `(?P=Q)` to work inside the character class `[^(?P=Q)]*` but this does not work unfortunately. The [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) would match any character besides `)(?=QP`.

For such scenario you would usually use what is known as [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) which will look like `(?:(?!(?P=Q)).)*` for your case. But for matching quoted parts with potential escaped quotes inside it's considerably more efficient and also readable to alternate between the options and use an *unrolled* pattern for each quote style. The `(?<Q>['"])[^(?P=Q)]*(?P=Q))` can be [replaced with](https://regex101.com/r/jhT8v7/1):

```
"(?:[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'(?:[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'
```

References:

- [Regex for quoted string with escaping quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786066/5527985)
- [Unrolling the loop](https://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop)