# PHP Regular Expression to grab values enclosed in double quotes

Tags: php, regex

This question is related to [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks), that I've tried to implement in my actual code, but with no success.

What I'd like to accomplish is to **parse PHP code**, and grab literal double-quoted strings inside the code to automatically fix wrong/bad/unsecure things.

Solutions using `token_get_all()` are not valid, as the PHP code may be not parsing correctly (invalid, broken, old PHP 4 code).

The regular expression should:

1. Match only if a double-quote is not preceeded by a single quote
2. Match only if a double-quote is not followed by a single quote
3. Also match backslashes inside the double-quoted string
4. Leave the start and trailing double quoted untouched (return it as part of the match)

To have an example of what the regexp should match, consider this parts of (ugly, old and unsecure) PHP code:

```
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
$sql = "UPDATE $table_name SET
password = password('$newpass'), pchange = '1'
WHERE email = '$email'";
$var = '"' . $something . '"';
$msg = "<p><a href=\"login.html\">Login</a></p>";
echo "<label for=\"whatever\">LABEL</label><select class='".$style."'>";
```

The regular expression should match:

1. `"Last-Modified: "`
2. `"D, d M Y H:i:s"`
3. `" GMT"`
4. `"UPDATE $table_name SET password = password('$newpass'), pchange = '1' WHERE email = '$email'"`
5. `"<p><a href=\"login.html\">Login</a></p>"`
6. `"<label for=\"whatever\">LABEL</label><select class='"`
7. `"'>"`

The regexp will be used within a `preg_match()` with `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`, to restart the search where the last match occurred, in this way:

```
$string_match = preg_match(**REGEXP_HERE**, $php_code, $text_in_double_quotes, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $last_pos);
if ($string_match) {
    list($text_in_double_quotes, $last_pos) = $text_in_double_quotes[0];
}
```

**Thank you!**

**P.S.**

For those asking why I'm bothering doing this, here's a [Working demo with the Regular Expression suggested by @bobblebubble](https://tio.run/##jVVtb@JGEP4c/4o5C8kmISZpvxEgyvW4y6lEoQmnqgo5tNhj7N6y6/OuQ9I2vz2dWRvIy0mtP4B3d/aZmWeeGRdZ8fTUPy2ywvNa9DuPdYIwgH6/H4wup4GXoUiwDP2xMPbwQid5mmPSAz9arhJhMfQ/dCCBC/gDznt5z/jtyIdPF1O/feK1zHdJUP6XyYez6QhaViwkzpVYIVyPpl4hjFnrMiGTzWsYtBSueRW0O1DEmVBLjiY4Drzfz0dXI8CVyBk0aLm3wCc3d6LkHT@ACFpGr9BmuVrSgrboeGWWHEW/GPYFZCWmg5kv9TJXUWZXcuYPx7zod8Ww3y2GBIhxpsleigVKSHVJ9uuMcr3Dkq3P3o/G/a47HfYNSowtxJJiHgR@1DL2QWLkBwxEBJ54XrcLBi3YDKHEJd6D1bASNs7ge6UtJmBsSfEar1UfUyrdWXDzdRbMZrPb/fC0R//Rdt3enwXh/vWvnyft8PRd@x//5qv/0tBv7PxuULvPVW5zIfO/0EXhShxLFKoqQGpdeC0i/xs5tmWFxJhOU454AK3cInN7RJtFiXe5rsx8e6oqKU@8dZZLDB1CG/72gJ762sEBeecl3VzOXcZhnWIHtlKjV3eCpgOTq9Gn@eXHjySO@S9nk@mXqxEd1@5ITgyVpxBuLmy88SNzY8NWTSSjazodbKFvjm5Ptqbbl7rMH3WlEhBNRYQFuusAetDg@aSkyflkProcNwnxQ7RWBXcA1AFuD56xx1AHXF6JahMdJeLt0WUrviGI2OZaGdAKWGGsjETDOrfZxnnPGR9HnDnXrt6F3AaGgr7@bUwiwvKhA2l@T7sQVoZgYV2KoqAapCpsMzrFD9QmOXegcQIkRSw5eobI1Z/oIqFSabJYmXbk/P702m@slRW5Ms6Fpg1RluKB8ojRGBe4riwYMpVYy9vsQsNo@bxBbzZNddt2zn6OalESr3A@vRjXOrXMS@MWKrUWilvGiqVpAPspHQ4JwoFEUfTsHnlGsxMb9Nw2UbfOHmCNoJCxKD0nYtcLIEgOdBQLpbQFpnOn37mQ0rmhWFIqXofpIeNaPDQqAO/FqpC45cff5et3nuEuiNKqbMKk7UzcIdelxEKKGJmvfebmYZ1hiftcw13PuBAWGAuOjsN3DBtHE97bw4UwlBdd4TMKsxJyoyfyFZDbXHVcokIavTFs5Wq@QLtGVPPGmEacXr/g9eWi5iKFN8OBguEseUJ0GFzRCESncSKfyGv8bJuFY3kN4u25bn8N/W5QTx5u/729HwQ9IGYX9B4@HzKvULZzBQ7fnFGH7pGY/leTvvEeQX3TEcv47y8vx5BK1ivro6kWNyFjGeoXmbAaEq3I1ULfUbTkgYYSlsYyL01Va9xdHV6uHhv9G9bRJqHNaNr7wfBu8q/n4qP7RUly2s3UzUchpVxwY@c1s09pQJVI7nruGkqOvsZGpNiM6bD@Bgzh@Oio/V@gj09P/wI) that shows exactly why I'm looking for such a particular regex (and why I can't use preg_match_all in this case)

Comment: String interpolation vs concatenation isn’t the security problem, it is allowing user-controlled inputs into the string in the first place. Please look into prepared statements.

Comment: Don't try to use regexp or validation to that. Just use prepared statements and there will be no risk as long as the charset and data type is correctly set.

Comment: @ChrisHaas the question is not about PHP secure patterns to use string concatenation in SQLs vs prepared statements, which I'm well aware of, is about writing a regexp to match quoted strings, also matching escaped double quotes and resilient on start/end single quotes. Thank you for your contribution, though.

Comment: @bobblebubble thank you very mutch! Your solution is _partially_ working as expected. Here's a working sandbox that uses the regexp you provided: https://php.land/s/63b005d560fd0929369096.
It did not match the last `"'>"` after `<select class='".$style.`.
Also, look at the following `<label for=\"debug\">`. Same thing, it did not match what come after (`"'>whatever<a href=\"#\">"`)

Comment: @bobblebubble the sandbox link I've provided is not persistent. Here's a gist with the actual prototype code: https://gist.github.com/mauriziofonte/bfbddbe5e8e5cf87a4a9ffce9dc55312

Comment: @Maurizio I posted an answer with a different concept (skip single quoted). Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [verbs](https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html) [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to exclude single quoted substrings.

```php
$regex = '/\'[^\'\\\]*(?:\\\.[^\'\\\]*)*\'(*SKIP)(?!)|"[^"\\\]*(?:\\\.[^"\\\]*)*"/';
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/b5Nilh/1) - The underlying pattern is [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786066/5527985).
To extract multiple items, use this regex with `preg_match_all` like that:

```php
if(preg_match_all($regex, $str, $out) > 0) {
  print_r($out[0]);    
}
```

[Here is a PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##VVHva9swEP3uv@ImDJJCZndfE8WhpWYZS2hYM0aJ26DaF8sg/5isNRvb/vbs1G2F6oN07@7x7t1pMMP5rJbb1TaK4tE7WIBSiuc3Ox4Z1BU6wdZ69G83fdUcG6xmwJK6rbRHwa6nUMEG7mA1a2YjkwmD95sdk3OS@mpJin3eXl/ucoi9frR46HSLcJvvokGP46l3FVH@h4LHHZ4C4nIKQ2l0VyPV@TsefVnln3LAVjdBlMfPEWfU5kkHx5xxSCAe@xa9abqaAKWo3I51cKGGTGkwDo@Lgtm@brrE@NYWLFsHoFKdqXTISBBL0xPf6ke0cOwd8U@GZn1CF9iXV/lapc/VTI1osfRQWvK84Cyh9f2wmDAehGiBc9qowxq/B4dpwfcPBS@K4n4iljN6kxcsJwUXk9uPH7ZSLN/IX2z/wF4T2T8eS2mqqDmKgYQPrfalOWhrxd8@Uwg/SHf/zUvI4ELCzwhgcE3nD06E9P7iXs6BTvQ7Op//AA), matches will be in `$out[0]` (full pattern).

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is working as expected. Please, also have a look at the original question, where I posted an example on TIO.run (thank you also for this one, I did not know this sandbox) in the P.S. section. That's why I cannot use preg_match_all().

Comment: @Maurizio Maybe you can use `preg_replace_callback` however, glad it works.